# Deep scan with oracle SQL/JSON

Tags: java, json, oracle, jsonpath

Java Jayway jsonpath uses the operator `..` to initiate a so-called *deep scan* ([see here](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started)). Is there something similar in oracle SQL/JSON? I looked at the oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADJSN/json-path-expressions.htm#ADJSN-GUID-2DC05D71-3D62-4A14-855F-76E054032494) but didn't find anything similar.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: "A path is indefinite if it contains: `..` - a deep scan operator". That tells me nothing about what the operator actually does so how are we meant to determine if Oracle has something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently SQL/JSON path expressions do not allow what you call 'deep scans' (or // in XPath).
Can you tell us more about the use case?
Do you really need to recursively nested arbitrarily deep into the json or can you enumerate the possible paths?
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need to look for "error" keys in a kind of logging nested structure. The "error" keys can be at many places and at many depths in the tree. So it is quite hard to enumerate all the possible paths in advance.